# Duplicate values showing everytime navigating to component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am getting the data from firebase and storing them in Vuex state. I am showing them in a list format using v-for in characters component. When the page loads for the first time the list of characters is showing perfectly but when I am navigation to other pages and coming back to characters again the list showing duplicate values.

```html
<ul class="characters-list">
        <li v-for="allHero in getAllHeros" v-bind:key="allHero.id">
          <router-link :to="{name: 'characterDetail', params: {id: allHero.id}}">
            <div class="hero-thumbnail">
              <img :src="allHero.imageUrl" :alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="hero-title">
              <h3>{{ allHero.name }}</h3>
            </div>
          </router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

```js
computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      "getAllHeros"
    ]),
}
methods: {
  ...mapActions(["fetchAllHeros"])
},
created() {
  this.fetchAllHeros();
}
```

```js
const state = {
    allHeros: [],
}

const getters = {
    getAllHeros: (state) => {
        return state.allHeros
    },
}

const actions = {
    fetchAllHeros: ({commit}) => {
        database.collection('heros').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let heros = doc.data();
                heros.id = doc.id
                //console.log(heros);
                commit('setAllHeros', heros)
            })
        })
    }
}

const mutations = { 
    setAllHeros: (state, payload) => {
        state.allHeros.push(payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include the code in the question?

Comment: What does your `getAllHeros` Vuex _getter_ do?

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle or anything similar?

Comment: So every time your component is created, you fetch all heroes and **append** them to the existing list. Do you see the problem there?

Comment: I am doing it for first time but after that when navigating to other routes and coming back to list page again its getting duplicated. Some kind of mistake i am doing here with vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a check to see if `allHeros` exists or not.

You could put this in `created()` or even in `fetchAllHeros`. if you put it in the action, then be sure to pass in `getters` along with `commit`.

```js
created() {
  if (this.getAllHeros.length < 1) {
    this.fetchAllHeros();
  }
}
```

```js
fetchAllHeros: ({commit, getters}) => {
  if (getters.getAllHeros.length > 0) {
   return;
  }

  // Keep the code you already have
  database.collection('heros').get()
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you please put the code if i want to pass it in action fetchAllHeros

Comment: Yah its working, but i think this is happening because of vuex, when am calling the database from the component it is not happening. When i am using vuex  this is happening. Is there any kind of method or i am doing any mistakes in state, actions, getters and in mutations. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

i too wasted much time figuring out this, finally i did like this,

- i had feed section,a list of posts

  - on vuex state i maintained

```
    feed:[],feedInitialLoad:false,
```

- once feed is first time loaded i mutate the feedInitialLoad:true, then
  then if i every time i visit the same route i would simply check on created hook

```
computed:{...mapState(['feedInitialLoad'])},
created(){
 if(!this.feedInitialLoad){
  //first time visit
   this.loadFeed();
   //mutate the feedInitialLoad to true 
 }  
}
```